# how to get firebase use in nextJS getserversideprops

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, next.js

I want to get 'sample' document in Firestore using getServerSideProps if there is signed user.
Code below doesn't work. It's result is 'can't read'
What should I do? or is there the other way?

```
export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  let currentUser = []

  authService.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if(user) {
        const docRef = dbService.collection('whole_users').doc('sample').get()
        await docRef.then((doc) => {
          if(doc.exists) {
            currentUser.push(doc.data())
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log("can't read")
      }
    })

  return {
    props: {currentUser}
  }
}
```

Comment: Where user in this line is pass from ? `authService.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {` did you try to log user value out ?

Comment: it's just "onAuthStateChanged" parameter.
I tried to put data in currentUser if there is data in "onAuthStateChanged".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first:
You call `get()` without an `await`. Chaneg your code to this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  let currentUser = []

  authService.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if(user) {
        const docRef = dbService.collection('whole_users').doc('sample')
        await docRef.get().then((doc) => {
          if(doc.exists) {
            currentUser.push(doc.data())
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log("can't read")
      }
    })

  return {
    props: {currentUser}
  }
}
```

The second: `onAuthStateChanged` is only for the client side. To access the auth state on the server side you would need to put the auth state into a provider. [Here](https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication) is an example how to do it.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work.
I wonder why I can't access "onAuthStateChanged" in getServerSideProps while i can access in component.

Comment: Ah sorry I just saw the wrong `get()` call. I have update the answer. Basicaly the best approach for this is to put the auth state into a provider so you can access it as expected. There is a link to an article explaining it in detail.