# Get the current Firebase user from Next.js getServerSideProps

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, next.js, firebase-admin

I'm looking for how to get the currently signed in Firebase user with Next.js through getServerSideProps. I've already tried using verifyIdAuthToken but I can't seem to change the persistence type through Firebase to get the cookie because I get this error:

```
[t [Error]: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.] {
  code: 'auth/unsupported-persistence-type',
  a: null
}
```

My current code is this:

```js
// utils/firebaseClient.js
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
    // redacted
}
if(!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
} else {
    firebase.app();
}

const auth = firebase.auth();
const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { firebase, googleProvider };
```

```js
// pages/dashboard.js
import { firebaseAdmin } from '../utils/firebaseAdmin';
import nookies from 'nookies';

export default function Dashboard({ user }) {

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Loading</h1>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hi</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  console.log(nookies.get(ctx));
  try {
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
    console.log(cookies);
    const user = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(cookies.token);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }
  return {}
}
```

```
// pages/index.js
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { googleProvider } from '../utils/firebaseClient';

export default function Authentication() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) window.location.replace('/dashboard');
  });

  const googleButton = () => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then((result) => {
      window.location.href = '/dashboard';
    }).catch((err) => {
      return console.log(err);
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={googleButton}>Login with Google</button>
    </> 
  )
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this, or if there is an alternate way to get the current Firebase user in getServerSideProps?

By the way, I have already read [how to get firebase use in nextJS getserversideprops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625554/how-to-get-firebase-use-in-nextjs-getserversideprops) and the solution didn't work for me. It also seems like it didn't work for the author of that question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add your sign in code to the question?

Comment: Added @Axiumin_

Comment: don't you have the user in the onAuthStateChanged callback?